# Google Wave Gadget: gadgets.window is undefined

Tags: google-gadget, google-wave

I'm learning Google Wave gadgets.

I'm trying to force [my gadget](http://gist.github.com/244697) to resize itself.

But I'm keep getting error that `gadgets.window` is undefined.

Here is my gadget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="GitHub Gist Gadget">
  <Require feature="wave" /> 
  <!--Require feature="locked-domain" /-->
  <Require feature="dynamic-heights" />
</ModulePrefs>
<Content type="html">
<![CDATA[ 
<div id="content_div"> 

<input type=button onclick="gadgets.window.adjustHeight()" />

<script src="http://gist.github.com/244697.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  gadgets.window.adjustHeight()
</script>

</div>
  ]]> 
  </Content>
</Module>
```

BTW, if you know about gadget to embed GitHub gists into Google Waves, please tell me. :-)

Comment: Did you ever finish this? I’ve been looking for a way to embed code in Waves. `Gist.GitHub` is *perfect* for this.

Comment: I think I've got it working (see gist), but never finished the gadget itself. Google Wave was way too slow to be useful those days.

Feel free to derive your work from the code in that gist, consider it under MIT license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace **dynamic-heights** with **dynamic-height**.

**gadgets.window.adjustHeight()** should be replaced with **gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(gadgets.window.adjustHeight)**, becouse gadgets.window may be not loaded while you initialize gadget.

Answer (score 1):

For the same problem but with igoogle gadget design.

i found out that the gadgets.window object was only available in the sandbox, but you can use the igoogle function:

```
_IG_AdjustIFrameHeight();
```

that will automatically adjust the iframe, igoogle.
;)

source: http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-resources/issues/detail?id=572